Input box not clearing after second letter input
I created some code to remove any letters that get typed within the input box. When I type in a letter, it gets removed from the UI and variable, however when I type in a letter again, it doesn't get removed from the UI but the code shows it gets removed from the variable. I don't understand why this is happening, I would like it to clear any letters that get typed into the text box automatically, and even have a button that clears it if I want. Here is my code:
@page "/"

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Value" @bind-value="InputValue" @oninput="HandleInput" />
<label for="modal_table_autosearch">Search by name</label>

<button type="button" @onclick="() => HandleInput(new ChangeEventArgs { Value = null })">
Clear Value
</button>

@code {
private string? InputValue { get; set; }

private async Task HandleInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Value is null)
    {
        InputValue = null;
        return;
    }

    var newValue = args.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

    InputValue = new string(newValue.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());

    await Task.Delay(1);
}
}


I guess your code does not work as you expect it because the binding of the textbox does not get updated on key pressed only the value gets updated but it is not rerendered in the UI. The interesting part is that the update is triggered when you enter a number instead of letter. I don't undestand that either. However:
Here is a working sample with

@bind-value:event="oninput"

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Value" @bind-value="InputValue" @bind-value:event="oninput">
<label for="modal_table_autosearch">Search by name</label>

<button type="button" @onclick="HandleButtonClick">
    Clear Value
</button>

@code {
    private string? _inputValue;

    private string? InputValue
    {
        get => _inputValue;
        set => _inputValue = new string(value?.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
    }

    private void HandleButtonClick()
    {
        InputValue = _inputValue;
    }
}


The problem is that you are setting the value to it's previous value.  The renderer doesn't recognise the change and therefore doesn't update the display.
Here's an updated version of HandleInput with comments to explain what's happening.
private async Task HandleInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        // get the entered value.  Trim off any spaces
        var value = args.Value?.ToString()?.Trim() ?? "";

        // Capture the current value
        var currentValue = this.InputValue;

        // Set the InputValue to a new value it can't be
        this.InputValue = " ";

        // Yield to allow the UI to render.  The renderer now believes the value is "  ".
        await Task.Delay(1);

        // If we have an empty string, set the InputValue to null
        if (value == "")
            currentValue = null;

        if (int.TryParse(value, out int newValue))
            // If we have a number update InputValue to the new value
            this.InputValue = newValue.ToString();
        else
            // Otherwise set InputValue back to currentValue
            this.InputValue = currentValue;

        // Final act is the component is renderered by the ComponentBase UI handler
    }

